# sum of odd numbers if placed in a triangular shape

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the pascal's triangle of odd numbers

```
         1
      3     5
    7    9    11
```

I want to create a function that returns the sum of odd numbers in relation to the  argument which is an **int** that represents the row in the pascal triangle.

```
               def row_sum(n):
                    #your code
```

if **n** is **2** output should be **8** that is **3+5**
and if **n** is **3** output  should be **27** that is **7+9+11** and so on for **n** in relation to the pascal's triangle.

I will appreciate understanding a simpler pythonic way of looping through the odd numbers and solving this problem.

Comment: We would appreciate a slightly more specific question from you: What have you tried? What does not work? Where is the error and how is its exact text? Where is your code? Please refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a  [minimal verifyable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question

Comment: `2*(n+1)+1` is the first element and then you just add 2 to the next element until you have total `n` elements. Would be straightforward using a range/arange/for loop. Try it out

Comment: This is no pascal triangle btw: read [Pascal triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle)

Answer (score 2):

If you work out the math....

```
def row_sum(n)
    return n**3
```

It just so happens that the row sums of the triangle you described are just the perfect cubes, in order.

Comment: you are a cheat'r ;)

Comment: Hey, part of programming is doing the hard thinking so that the computer doesn't have to...

Comment: Nah - just use the most complex calculation possible - let hardware solve the rest ;o) - you got my +1 already

Comment: Lol <filler chars>